# How to design a fitness function for the 8-queens problem?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, fitness-functions, evolutionary-computation, fitness-design, 8-queens-problem

In evolutionary computation and, in particular, in the context of genetic algorithms, there is the concept of a [*fitness function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function). The better a state, the greater the value of the fitness function for that state.

What would be a good fitness function for the [8-queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://kushalvyas.github.io/gen_8Q.html) you can find an example of how to apply genetic algorithms to solve the 8-queens problem.

The proposed fitness function is based on the chessboard arrangement, and in particular, it is inversely proportional to the number of clashes amongst attacking positions of queens; thus, a high fitness value implies a low number of clashes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated quite easily in the context of 8-queen problem. Just start with a particular configuration. Starting from the queen in the left-most column just keep on counting the non-attacking positions (pairs) on the right with each queen. Carry on column by column towards your right until you reach the last queen. As a special case for the last queen the non-attacking pairs will be zero as their are no other queens after that.

Comment: This describes how to solve the problem, but it doesn't answer the question which is about  formulating this as a fitness function to use in evolutionary computing.